# Mongoose save() returning old version, not saved version of document

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I must be missing something, but it seems that my `Document.prototype.save()` is not working for me properly in Mongoose 5.2.10.

[The docs say](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) that the callback returns the **saved document**.

> The callback will receive two parameters
>
> - `err` if an error occurred
> - `product` **which is the saved** `product`

For me, it seems to be returning the original version of the document before the update and save. Either I'm doing something wrong, or the docs are a little misleading or vague.

After calling save, the document is updated in the database, but the callback returns the old document, before the modification.

I have been calling save like this (inside an async function):

```
const myDocument = await User.findOne({ name: 'billy' });
const updatedInfo = {
    foo: 'update here',
    bar: 'some other new stuff'
};
myDocument.update({ $set: updatedInfo }, (err) => { console.log(err) });
myDocument.save((err, savedDoc) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    // Should return saved doc here
    console.log(savedDoc);
});
```

And like this:

```
myDocument.update({ $set: updatedInfo }, (err) => { console.log(err) });
myDocument.save().then((savedDoc) => {
    // Should return saved doc here
    console.log(savedDoc);
}).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

But can't get it to return me the saved document. `savedDoc` ends up being the old version of the document, while the new version does get saved in the database.

Comment: Please look into this link `https://davidburgos.blog/return-updated-document-mongoose/`

Comment: Thank you for that link. I had seen that but I am actually asking about something different. Rather than querying and updating the document, I want to know how to get the saved version of a document already queried. There is a good discussion with the Mongoose folks going on here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [the help of some of the Mongoose collaboraters](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6993), I discovered that **the problem was that I was using the `document.update()` function along with the `document.save()` function.**

The `document.update()` function is a separate async operation with a callback, and as mentioned by @Industrial Comet it does not return a document.

In order to make changes that will be applied in a saved, returned version of the document you need to apply each change directly to the document object in the form of:

```
myDocument.foo = 'new info';  
myDocument.bar = 'other new info';
myDocument.save((err, newDocument) => {
   // new Document available here
});
```

**EDIT:**

[I found out](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6993#issuecomment-420759326) **you can also update a bunch of different values with an object** of updated information using `myDocument.set(objectOfUpdatedInfo)` and then get a the saved document returned with `myDocument.save()`.

So my solution is to do this:

```
myDocument.set(objectOfUpdatedInformation);
myDocument.save().then((savedDoc) => {
    res.json({ response: 'success' savedDoc: savedDoc });
}).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

Below is my initial assesment of the situation before I knew that `document.protype.save()` existed. (Caused myself extra grief for not thoroughly reading the documentation)

<s>But I wanted to update my document with a chunk of different fields in an object. I was hoping to be able to do this and then get an updated document. It looks like I can't do this with `myDocument.update(objectOfUpdatedInfo)` because:</s>

- <s>the `.update()` method doesn't provide the updated info in the callback</s>
- <s>if I use save after the `.update()` method, the changes don't show up in the returned, saved document.</s>

<s>So my options are either:</s>

- <s>Apply the changes to individual keys/values in the object and then `.save()` it.</s>
- <s>Requery the object and update it with `Collection.findOneAndUpdate()`.</s>

<s>Both `Document.save()` and `Collection.findOneAndUpdate()` return an updated document, but `Document.save()` doesn't work well with `Document.update()`, and `Document.update()` doesn't return a document.</s>

<s>I would love to have the ability to cleanly plug an object full of updated info into an already queried `myDocument` object, and then get a return of the update document, but unfortunately right now this doesn't seem possible in Mongoose. I asked about this and there may be further discussion [in this github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6993). For now, this is my chosen solution using updates with computed key values:</s>

```
// Need to a document with an object full of values...
for (var property in updatedInfo) {
    myDocument[property] = updatedInfo[property];
}
myDocument.save().then((savedDoc) => {
    res.json({ response: 'success' savedDoc: savedDoc });
}).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `findOneAndUpdate` with `{new : true}` to get new version

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({statue: 'active'}, {$set:{qtt:0}}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: This is possbile, but with my use case it would be nice if I could update a document I've already been looking at with having to re-find it and update. There's more discussion going on here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6993

Answer (score -2):

Mongoose Update Function doesn't return the updated Doc. Also, changes made using the update function are a separate asynchronous operation, and shouldn't be used in conjunction with the update function.

1. Query the Document First
2. Modify the Document by assigning new values to individual keys
3. Save and Return the updated doc

   docs.findById(id,(err,myDocument)=> {
       //Selecting the Document you want to change
       myDocument.foo = //Updated Content
       myDocument.save((err,newDocument)=> {
           //Returns New Doc
       })
   })

Comment: I am querying the document first, I just didn't include that in my code above. Now I've edited it to show.